# In A-Frame Vive controller model not shown

Tags: aframe, webvr, htc-vive

I write a A-Frame 0.8.2 project.

The Vive controller can be added in scene and the interaction events work well.

But the model of Vive controller is not shown.

[image]

The red line is the laser of Vive controller.

I tried to add model with a extra entity, but it not works.

```
<a-entity id="viveControllerRight" vive-conrols="hand: right" debug_tool>
    <!-- Defining the URL inline. Not recommended but may be more comfortable. -->
    <!--<a-obj-model src="https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/vive/vr_controller_vive.obj" mtl="https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/vive/vr_controller_vive.mtl"></a-obj-model>-->
</a-entity>
```

Update:

Only use the laser-controls, and the most atributtes are as default.

```
<a-entity id="leftHand" laser-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
<a-entity id="rightHand" laser-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
```

[image]

The model of controller is not really hidden. It covers the cursor, when it is front of cursor. But its form is not shown.

Demo: http://webvr.virtualskillslab.de/0.8.0/\

Github: https://github.com/LeMueller/skills-lab-web (in develop branch)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1. You have a typo. It is `vive-controls` instead of `vive-conrols`.
2. You don't need to add the model manually it comes built-in with [vive-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/vive-controls.html#value_model). You just have to do the following to show the model:

   `<a-entity id="viveControllerRight" vive-controls="hand: right" debug_tool><a-entity>`
3. `laser-controls` already applies the different vendor specific controls on your behalf. No need to add `oculus-controls`, `daydream-controls`... manually. See [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/laser-controls.html#sidebar)
4. From your screenshot, SteamVR detects a single controller and your application only includes controls for the right hand. If the controller is identified as left hand it won't show up. Add controls for both right and left hands.

I recommend the [`laser-controls` example](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/) as starting point:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/test/laser-controls/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I correct the spell, but it is still the same as before. Maybe it is not the reason.

Comment: Hi Diago, I fund the reason. If I set the version of A-Frame back to 0.8.0, would be the controllers shown. But the emition of click event with cursor or controllers on 0.8.0 is not realy correct. The interaction on 0.8.2 is well, but the model of Vive controller would not be shown. Gear VR controller is all correct on 0.8.2.

Comment: Just tried the laser controls example (https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/) and everything works as expected. Vive model renders. Your application is pretty complicated, if you reduced the issue to a simple test case it will be easier to investigate.

Comment: I will check it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Diago, I have checked the show of Vive controller with the basic scene from official site. Under 0.8.2 are the controllers hidden. Under 0.7.0 are the controllers shown. It is the same as in my project.
Glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/e229cdbe-898d-41c8-b329-ccd68bf3b6b7

Comment: Try A-Frame master: https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/5d5590d/dist/aframe-master.min.js